# UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure

Tags: selenium, java, cucumber, chromedriver

I am trying to launch Chrome browser with cucumber script and getting:
I'm Using Cucumber Selenium Script 
Selenium - 2.53.1

```
[31mFailure in before hook:[0m[31mLoginWorkFlow_StepDefinition.beforeFeature()[0m
[31mMessage: [0m[31morg.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1cd5757287168e54b817830adce9b0158d', time: '2016-06-30 19:26:09'
System info: host: 'JKCS-LASITHA', ip: '10.2.241.46', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:665)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:249)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:144)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:170)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:159)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:116)
    at com.jkcs.Config.stepDefinitions.BaseStepDefinition.driverSetup(BaseStepDefinition.java:126)
    at com.jkcs.Config.stepDefinitions.LoginWorkFlow_StepDefinition.beforeFeature(LoginWorkFlow_StepDefinition.java:176)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at cucumber.runtime.Utils$1.call(Utils.java:37)
    at cucumber.runtime.Timeout.timeout(Timeout.java:13)
    at cucumber.runtime.Utils.invoke(Utils.java:31)
    at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaHookDefinition.execute(JavaHookDefinition.java:60)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runHookIfTagsMatch(Runtime.java:223)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runHooks(Runtime.java:211)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runBeforeHooks(Runtime.java:201)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberScenario.run(CucumberScenario.java:40)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberFeature.run(CucumberFeature.java:165)
    at cucumber.api.testng.TestNGCucumberRunner.runCucumber(TestNGCucumberRunner.java:63)
    at cucumber.api.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.feature(AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.java:21)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:86)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:643)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:820)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1128)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:129)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:112)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:782)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:632)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:366)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:361)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:319)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:268)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1244)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1169)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1064)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:132)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:230)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:76)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1cd5757287168e54b817830adce9b0158d', time: '2016-06-30 19:26:09'
System info: host: 'JKCS-LASITHA', ip: '10.2.241.46', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:91)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:644)
    ... 47 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.streamRead(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:139)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.fillBuffer(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:155)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.readLine(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:284)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:140)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:57)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:261)
    at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:165)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.receiveResponseHeader(CPoolProxy.java:167)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:272)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:124)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:271)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:71)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.fallBackExecute(ApacheHttpClient.java:144)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.execute(ApacheHttpClient.java:90)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:142)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:82)
    ... 48 more
[0m
      [31morg.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
      Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1cd5757287168e54b817830adce9b0158d', time: '2016-06-30 19:26:09'
      System info: host: 'JKCS-LASITHA', ip: '10.2.241.46', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
      Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:665)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:249)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:144)
        at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:170)
        at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:159)
        at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:116)
        at com.jkcs.Config.stepDefinitions.BaseStepDefinition.driverSetup(BaseStepDefinition.java:126)
        at com.jkcs.Config.stepDefinitions.LoginWorkFlow_StepDefinition.beforeFeature(LoginWorkFlow_StepDefinition.java:176)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at cucumber.runtime.Utils$1.call(Utils.java:37)
        at cucumber.runtime.Timeout.timeout(Timeout.java:13)
        at cucumber.runtime.Utils.invoke(Utils.java:31)
        at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaHookDefinition.execute(JavaHookDefinition.java:60)
        at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runHookIfTagsMatch(Runtime.java:223)
        at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runHooks(Runtime.java:211)
        at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runBeforeHooks(Runtime.java:201)
        at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberScenario.run(CucumberScenario.java:40)
        at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberFeature.run(CucumberFeature.java:165)
        at cucumber.api.testng.TestNGCucumberRunner.runCucumber(TestNGCucumberRunner.java:63)
        at cucumber.api.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.feature(AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.java:21)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:86)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:643)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:820)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1128)
        at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:129)
        at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:112)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:782)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:632)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:366)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:361)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:319)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:268)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1244)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1169)
        at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1064)
        at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:132)
        at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:230)
        at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:76)
      Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
      Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1cd5757287168e54b817830adce9b0158d', time: '2016-06-30 19:26:09'
      System info: host: 'JKCS-LASITHA', ip: '10.2.241.46', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
      Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:91)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:644)
        ... 47 more
      Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.streamRead(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:139)
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.fillBuffer(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:155)
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.readLine(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:284)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:140)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:57)
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:261)
        at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:165)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.receiveResponseHeader(CPoolProxy.java:167)
        at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:272)
        at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:124)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:271)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:71)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.fallBackExecute(ApacheHttpClient.java:144)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.execute(ApacheHttpClient.java:90)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:142)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:82)
        ... 48 more
```

Comment: Which version of Chrome are you running?

Comment: I'm using Google Chrome Version 59.0.3071.115 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: And which version of ChromeDriver?

Comment: version of ChromeDriver is 2.20

Comment: Could you share the ChromeDriver instantiation code steps, would be helpful?

Comment: Starting ChromeDriver 2.20.353145 (343b531d31eeb933ec778dbcf7081628a1396067) on port 42789
Only local connections are allowed.

Comment: Can you please update your ChromeDriver to 2.30 and try again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unreachable browser exception comes when the session is closed or browser is not launched but web-driver is trying to access the browser or some elements on it.

Let's make it simple.

1. Set web driver property first.

`System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe"); 
driver = new ChromeDriver();`

2. Make sure you have the latest or compatible (Chrome, Gecko or IE)driver.exe file.
3. If the issue remains the same then, re start Eclipse or any IDE you are using. Update project and re run the test.

Answer (score 0):

This has been asked in the Stack Overflow community as well. See

- [After run a SoapUI, could not start selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39403993/after-run-a-soapui-could-not-start-selenium)
- [Selenium UnreachableBrowserException - “Could not start a new session” in SoapUI Groovy TestStep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30397043/selenium-unreachablebrowserexception-could-not-start-a-new-session-in-soapui)

The answer posted by user albciff, adding a `ProxySelector`, worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why this happens,

When the test does not get executed within 3 minutes(Default timing), then it will throw the exception of **browser startup failure**.

**Solution**:- Change the way to create RemoteWebDriver.

```
    ClientConfig config = ClientConfig.defaultConfig().connectionTimeout(Duration.ofMinutes(20))
.readTimeout(Duration.ofMinutes(20)); // I change this 3 minute(Default) to 20 minutes.

WebDriver remoteWebDriver = RemoteWebDriver.builder().oneOf(caps).address(gridUrl).config(config).build(); // now you can use this remoteWebDriver.
```